# how to delete element when click on button only not on all div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how to delete element when press on delete button?
but what happened here when i press any where in div the div will delete

i am trying to delete using button only

```
<script>
  function myexfun(mySelectID, selectedItem, myDIVId) {
    var x = document.getElementById(mySelectID).value;
    $('#parentcur').append('<div id="childcur" class="row mg-l-20 mg-t-40 mg-lg-t-0 "><div class="col-lg-3 mg-t-40 mg-lg-t-0"><label class="rdiobox rdiobox-primary"><input name="rdio" type="radio" checked="" id="rdcur"><span id="selectedItemcur" class="mg-l-20 mg-t-40">' + x + '</span></label></div><div class=" mg-t-40 mg-l-auto mg-lg-t-0"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mg-r-20 mg-t-5 rm" type="button" value="Delete" id="bdd"onClick="delelm()" title="Delete Row"><span class="icon ion-trash-a"></span> Delete</button></div></div>');
    // bd.style.display = "block";

  }
</script>
<script>
  function delelm() {
    $(document).on("click", '#childcur', function() {
      $(this).remove();
    });
  }
</script>
```

i tried alot but i can not delete it from button just click on div

Comment: which element are you trying to delete here?

Comment: GIve your html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your click event listener is attached to the entire div, which is why it deletes whenever you click anywhere inside the div. Since you have `delelm()`, you can modify the code as below to confine the click to just the delete button alone.

```js
$('#parentcur').append('<div id="childcur" class="row mg-l-20 mg-t-40 mg-lg-t-0 "><div class="col-lg-3 mg-t-40 mg-lg-t-0"><label class="rdiobox rdiobox-primary"><input name="rdio" type="radio" checked="" id="rdcur"><span id="selectedItemcur" class="mg-l-20 mg-t-40">1</span></label></div><div class=" mg-t-40 mg-l-auto mg-lg-t-0"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mg-r-20 mg-t-5 rm" type="button" value="Delete" id="bdd"onClick="delelm(this)" title="Delete Row"><span class="icon ion-trash-a"></span> Delete</button></div></div>');

function delelm(el) {
  $(el).closest('#childcur').remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="parentcur"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're targeting clicks on the `#childcur` div and not it's children.

Here's an example of how this could be done:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="deletable">
    <p>A</p>
    <button class="do-delete">Delete</button>
  </div>

  <div class="deletable">
    <p>B</p>
    <button class="do-delete">Delete</button>
  </div>

  <div class="deletable">
    <p>C</p>
    <button class="do-delete">Delete</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
// target buttons within the divs we want to be deletable.
$('div.deletable > button.do-delete').on('click', function() {
    // when the button is clicked, access the parent and remove it from the DOM.
    $(this).parent().remove();
})
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7aro46et/